# Why NoScript tag is not working in all browsers

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I am using NoScript tag in my jsp pages in head section. I am using tiles and taking care not to keep multiple NoScript tags because of tiles. But still in i.e. its not working.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Post the HTML please.

Comment: And define what you mean by 'not working'.

Answer (score 3):

The noscript tag only detects whether the browser has JavaScript enabled or not. If JavaScript is disabled in the Firewall rather than in the browser then the JavaScript will not run and the content of the noscript tag will not be displayed.

you will get more differences from here :[Reasons to Avoid Noscript](http://javascript.about.com/od/reference/a/noscriptnomore.htm)

Comment: I got the problem through your answer. Its firewall that is making this trouble, because I was trying on IE through a network which is behind firewall. Thanks a lot! But why I am not able to accept your answer on SO? I am a new user.

Comment: You can only accept answer after 15 minutes of asking question lol :)

Comment: `noscript` tag is deprecated  in XHTML, don't use it

Answer (score -1):

don't use `NoScript`it is abrogated. if you want to check whether javascript is enabled or not use the following method : (this code is in php because I donno jsp but you can change it to jsp)

```
<script>
    window.location='somePage.jps' //you can be sure that somepage.jps is JavaScript enabled 
</script>
<?php
    print 'Javascript is not enabled'; // here add your html/css code for non-js page
?>
```

Comment: what this <?php  ?> will do? I am not clear with it. Could you please explain a bit more?

Comment: `<?php` is starting tag of php code, it means from this tag on, it is php code. you must replace it with jsp code

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using `noscript`, it is still alive and well in HTML5. http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics.html#the-noscript-element

Comment: @sevenseacat This text is from book `Beginning_Javascript_With_DOM_Scripting_And_AJAX` page 7:                  `There is also an “opposite” to the script tag—noscript—which allows you to add content that
will only be displayed when JavaScript is not available. However, noscript is deprecated in XHTML and strict
HTML, and there is no need for it` my method is taken from this book. as you can see there is something wrong with `noscript`

Comment: @sevenseacat you can download this book from [here](http://uppit.com/nj8zhdwq5dav/book.rar) to check it up

Comment: What the book says is bogus. Check the actual HTML specifications.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela the writer of that book is technology developer at Yahoo company, and Apress published the book. I think you are not even in the position of saying that book is bogus

Comment: I posted the *actual HTML specification* saying it's valid. I don't really care what your book says.